# can I get rid of virus, by re-imaging the 32 bits desktop with Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, malware

Wanted to use Ubuntu to recover data from corrupted external hard drive.

So happened have to re-image a 32 bits Vista desktop to get rid of virus.

How do I re-image the desktop with Ubuntu ? Do I re-format the desktop internal hard drive before or after installing Ubuntu ? and How ? don't want vista anymore.

Thanks in advance. (I'm a complete Ubuntu novice and complete idiot about pc desktop)

Geoff

Comment: What makes you think you have a virus on Ubuntu that would force you to reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

If you no longer need any of the data on the desktop's hard drive (i.e. the files from when you used Vista), then you can install Ubuntu on the desktop from a Live CD. When it gives you the options for formatting and partitioning, choose the option that will use the whole drive, with default partition options. This will install Ubuntu on the desktop's hard drive and you won't have to worry about any viruses that were on that hard drive before, since it is a fresh install.

Then you can use Ubuntu to access files on the external drive. If there are also viruses on the external drive, you will need to be careful about what files you copy off it (especially if you are planning to copy them back to another Windows computer).

Comment: Thanks heaps Jet86. I have free download version 12.0 (?) on USB. My old crapey desktop only boots from CD or hard drive. Guess I'll have to get Ubunto on CD. Still Big Thanks to Jet86 for pin-pointing my silly question spot on. Cheers.